# ResponseCache For Spesific Customer in Dotnet

Tags: .net, responsecache

In my project I wanna use ResponseCache, for example this is my controller;

```
[Route("/user/getrosetteRewardStatu")]
        [Authorize(Roles = "SelectedPos", AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(BaseResponse<GetRosetteInfoResponse>), 200)]
        [Consumes("application/json")]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<GetrosetteRewardStatuResponse> GetrosetteRewardStatu()
        {
            return await mediator.Send(new GetrosetteRewardStatuRequest() { CustomerCode = HttpContext.User.Claims.ToCustomerCode() });
        }
```

I want to cache the repsonse only for this CustomerCode parameter.

How can I do that?